# JavaFX Application can't be open and loads in task manager

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'making an application with JavaFX and Scene Builder.  I'm using Intelij IDEA.

When running an application from IDEA it works perfectly fine.

I wanted to build my application as exe file just to check if this gonna run on other computers.

I had made exe file with included JRE. JAR file also included after building artifacts.

That is how I made this:

File/Project Structure/Artifacts

My project appears here.I created MANIFEST file in the folder src. I added Main class.

[image: Artifacts]

I added Application Class in JavaFX Tab and chose ALL in Native Bundle options

[image: JavaFX Tab]

I cliked "Apply" and "OK" buttons

I Made build - Build/build artifacts

Intelij Idea created a folder with my app's name in out/artifacts. There are also JAR file and EXE file

[image: Builded]

When I click on EXE file application begin to install. After installation is complete I try to run my program, but nothing happens. Instead of this application runs in task manager and consume some resources. The same situation occurs with JAR file when I try to open it by double-clicking .

[image: Task Manager]

**What should I do to run my application in a appropriate way without any bugs?**

My Java Version:

[image: Java Version]

Manifest file:

[image: Manifest file]

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOUND!**

There is Available Elements Tab in Artifacts panel. All used libraries placed there. I just added all libraries from there to my project to make build

[image: Available Elements]